# Looking for a better alternative for using Javascript to subtract time from Kendo UI timepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I currently have an Asp.net MVC 4 application with a screen for Time entry. On this screen I use some various Kendo controls and Razor Html helpers for example:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m => m.StartTime).Name("startTime"))
```

I have the samething for endTime as well. Right now I have some Javascript that correctly handles my desired outcome, although the rounding could be better, but it is messy and I'm sure there is a better way to handle it. That code looks something like this:

```
function change() {
        var startTime = $("#startTime").val()
        var endTime = $("#endTime").val()
        var start = "01/01/2015 " + startTime
        var end = "01/01/2015 " + endTime
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date(end) - new Date(start));
        var d = timeDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60
        var diffM = d * 2
        var diffR = Math.ceil(diffM)
        var diff = diffR / 2

        $('#HoursWorked').val(diff)
        $('#TotalBillTime').val(diff)
    }
```

The outcome I want is the EndTime to be Subtracted from the StartTime, and the difference to be converted and rounded to be displayed as an HoursWorked count in hours. Right now it does hours and half hours. Is there a way to avoid all of this extra code? Also mathematically is there a way to round this more precisely or to include hours, half hours, and quarter hours?

I apologize if this is a bad question I am newer to Javascript and not familiar with many additional libraries or objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
function change() {
    var startTime = $("#startTime").val()
    var endTime = $("#endTime").val()
    var start = "01/01/2015 " + startTime
    var end = "01/01/2015 " + endTime
    var timeDiff = moment(end) - moment(start);
    var diff = moment.duration(timeDiff).asHours();

    $('#HoursWorked').val(diff)
    $('#TotalBillTime').val(diff)
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, that didn't answer your question about representing the hours in full, half and quarter increments. For that you still need to employ some maths. The formula you need is:

```
Math.ceil(hours * 4) / 4
```

For example:

```
> Math.ceil(1.053 * 4) / 4
1.25
> Math.ceil(1.50001 * 4) / 4
1.75
> Math.ceil(1.4999 * 4) / 4
1.5
```

So going back to the example:

```
var diff = moment.duration(timeDiff).asHours();
var roundedDiff = Math.ceil(diff * 4) / 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, JavaScript's date functions are severely lacking. It's absurd.

Second, there is several cool frameworks to make it better.

Countdown allows you to represent the diff between two dates easily.
http://countdownjs.org/

Moment.js makes overall date handling SO much better.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: That's something I'm starting to see with Javascript. Thank you for the references moment.js was exactly what I was looking for and I'll be looking into countdownjs more.